# How to redirect Main Tab to Nested Tab Using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, tabs

I'm working On tab, I'm getting problem When I Redirect Tab. I need To Redirect Nested Tab On click Main Tab It Is Possible ?

MyScript

```js
    $(".parentTabs a.nav-link").on("click", function () {
    alert();
        var curId = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active show");
        $(".nav-justified .nav-link").removeClass("active");
        $(".tab-pane" + curId).addClass("active show");
    });

    $(".chieldTabs a.chield-nav").on("click", function () {
        $(".chieldTabs a.chield-nav").removeClass("active show");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var curId = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".sub_tab_active").removeClass("active show");
        $(".tab-pane" + curId).addClass("active show");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="tabbable boxed parentTabs">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#set1" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#set2" class="nav-link">Payment</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#sub22" class="nav-link">Cash</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="set1">
                                <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set2">
                                <div class="tabbable chieldTabs">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                        <li class="active"><a class="chield-nav" href="#sub21">Cash</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="chield-nav" href="#sub22">OnHand</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade sub_tab_active" id="sub21">
                                            <h2>Cash</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade sub_tab_active" id="sub22">
                                            <h2>OnHand</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="set3">
                                <h2>OhHand</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I'm Using `Bootstrap 4`

Here I'm Set Example of My Problem Please Check One. I need To redirect OnHandTab On Click Of Main Cash Tab

This My Damo For Tabs, I need To Redirect `OnhandTab` On Click `Parent Cash Tab` It Is Possible ?
Thank You

Comment: What it the problem? What problems are you facing with this code?